# string "3/21/2013" is not recognized as valid datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to convert a string to a datetime format in C#.

```
DateTime SnapDate = Convert.ToDateTime(valid(odr, 4)).Date;

protected string valid(OleDbDataReader myreader, int stval)//if any columns are found null then they are replaced by zero
{
   object val = myreader[stval];
   if (val != DBNull.Value)
      return val.ToString();
   else
   return Convert.ToString("");
}
```

And it gives me the following error: "The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is a unknown word starting at index 0."

I tried several things like: `parse` and `parseExact` but still didn't get it.

I am reading this data from an excel sheet.

Comment: We'll need to see `valid(...)`

Comment: Current row.. reading from excel

Comment: What is the actual result of the call to "valid"?

Comment: updated code with valid function. it just checks for null values

Comment: What should `Convert.ToDateTime("")` return, in your opinion?  It's unrelated to this problem but will be your next problem.

Comment: Austin: Date and Time format 3/21/2013 12:00

Comment: What is the data type of the column in the database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your input string is in en-US format. Try specifying `CultureInfo` object into `Parse` method:

```
DateTime SnapDate = DateTime.Parse(valid(odr, 4), new CultureInfo("en-US")).Date;
```

It will force `Parse` method to look for date in `M/d/yyyy` format, which is valid for your input string of `3/21/2013`.

Comment: The type or namespace name 'CultureInfo' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: add `using System.Globalization` at the top of the file.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say rather than using your system culture or choosing one, pick the exact date format and use that, like:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("3/21/2013", "M\\/d\\/yyyy", null);
```

No ambiguity on the order of parameters, or on the date separator.

FYI: The reason I use a backslash before the forward-slash is to escape the forward-slash - forward-slash means [date separator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator), not necessarily the forward-slash, so escaping it removes any possible ambiguity.

Comment: Personally I'd go for ISO 8601 for string representation of dates unless it is to/from a user interface.

Comment: @ColinMackay I agree 200%. Either that or `yyyyMMdd` or `yyyyMMddHHmmssfff` with no punctuation if I need to keep the size small for whatever reason.

Comment: I prefer keeping my short-date format as yyyy-MM-dd in Windows for a couple reasons - I prefer to look at it that way - and also if someone wrote code that expects MM/dd/yyyy and mixes that with `ToShortDateString` or something, then it blows up and I can see that there will be a problem.

Comment: Tried this but got an error: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: That's a pretty good idea. I might not do that on my own machine, but setting that up on the build server will show it up when it runs though the unit tests.

Comment: @aahmed325 what was the input string? Perhaps the string really wasn't a valid DateTime.